# Chrome extension select folder for several downloads

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that scrapes pages and downloads images within the page. However, I've run into a sort of roadblock.

Since the extension is designed to download several files at once, I'd like for the user to be able to click the 'Download' button, select a folder, then download all the images to that folder.

So far, the only thing I've seen that might be of use is the `saveAs` option in `chrome.downloads.download()`. However, it would be very tedious for the user to have to select a location and confirm for every file. Is there a way I can have the user select a folder, then just download all the files to that specific folder?

Let me know if I need to include any specific code. Figured it wasn't very important, since I don't even have code pertaining to this question currently.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot. Your options are

1. Ask the user each time
2. Save the files to the downloads folder set by the user or a sub folder
3. Although much more complicated you could use native messaging and have native code communicate with the extension. You could then wait for the extension to complete the download and then send a message to your native host with the full path. Then your native host can move the file to where you want.